# Who should decide? The caller or the business logic of method? Architecture style

Tags: java, oop, generics, methods, architecture

Yesterday I had a discussion about an architecture coding style and if the caller of a method or the logic of the method should decide something.

**How its done for now (simplified):**

There is a class `Page` which has a `List<Hotel>` as attribute.

```
public class Page {
    private String name;
    private List<Hotel> hotels;
}
```

There was a decision to have the business logic inside the method so that the caller does not care about how the page information are set in.

```
public void fillPageWithHotels(Page page, List<DummyInfo> dummyInfos){
    //business logic...
    List<Hotel> hotels = new ArrayList<>();
    for(DummyInfo di : dummyInfos){
        //create a hotel instance and fill the infos of dummy inside hotel attributes
        Hotel h = new Hotel(di.getName());
        //many other information set to hotel attributes...
        hotels.add(h);
    }
    //important part here. The List of hotels is set here to the page 
    page.setHotels(hotels);
}
```

**First Question:** Is this a good design or should the method return a `List<Hotel>`?

**Why I asked this question:**

Now I have another class which extends Hotel. `public class HotelDetail extends Hotel` The `HotelDetail` will be now also an attribute in `Page` object.

And I also have to call the `fillPageWithHotels` method. But now I need not a `Hotel` but a `HotelDetail` instance.

The caller cant decide if he needs `Hotel` or `HotelDetail`.

- So inside the method you need the do the decision
  `if(decisionIsHotel){ new Hotel()} else {new HotelDetail()}` and give it to page. (What I personally dont like)
- Or should the method now be generic? Means put out `Page` from method parameter and have a generic return type.
  `public <T extends Hotel> T fillPageWithHotels(List<DummyInfo> dummyInfos){}`?
- or other better code/architecture styles.

What is the best architecture style for this problem?

---

**Edit1:**

My first approach: I dont give `Page` as method parameter and give instead a genric return type back:

```
public <T extends Hotel> List<T> fillPageWithHotels(Class<T> c, List<DummyInfo dummyInfos){
    //business logic...
    List<T> hotels = new ArrayList<>();
    for(DummyInfo di : dummyInfos){
        //create a hotel instance and fill the infos of dummy inside hotel attributes
        T t = c.newInstance();
        //many other information set to hotel attributes...
        hotels.add(t);
    }
    return hotels;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion managing state of method's parameter is not a good idea.

If method is part of a class we can simply remove first parameter:

```
class Page {
    ...
    public void fillPageWithHotels(List<DummyInfo> dummyInfos){
        ...
        setHotels(hotels);
    }
}
```

Otherwise it could be utility method:

```
class Factory {
    public static List<Hotel> createHotels(List<DummyInfo> dummyInfos){
        ...
    }
}
...
page.setHotels(Factory.createHotels(dummyInfos));
```

The caller can't specify generic if he can't decide what type he needs.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Updated my answer with another approach. What do you think?

Comment: As I said generics are useless if user of this method can't decide which implementation of Hotel he needs as return type. One of OOP principles says "Program to an interface not an implementation"

Comment: My previous comment applies to your initial goal "the caller does not care about how the page information are set in".